# Count with Case Select in Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, case

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t.range,
       Count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN creditscore BETWEEN 300
                    AND 499
                THEN '[300, 499]'
            WHEN creditscore BETWEEN 500
                    AND 699
                THEN '[500, 699]'
            WHEN creditscore BETWEEN 700
                    AND 850
                THEN '[700, 850]'
            END AS range
    FROM customer
    ) T
GROUP BY t.range;
```

Which gives me the following :

```
CS range     COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
[700, 850]          7
[500, 699]         13
```

I want the following output:

```
CS range     COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
[300, 499]          0
[500, 699]         13
[700, 850]          7
```

Can anyone help me out?

**UPDATE**

I executed the code the Justin provided. It gives me the following:

```
DESCRIPTIO   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
[300, 499]          1
[700, 850]          7
[500, 699]         13

SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer where creditscore BETWEEN 300 AND 499;

COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

Comment: Create a temporary table with the ranges, then `LEFT JOIN` it to your results, replacing the null with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to do something like

```
WITH ranges AS (
  SELECT '[300, 499]' description, 300 min_val, 499 max_val FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '[500, 699]' description, 500 min_val, 699 max_val FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '[700, 850]' description, 700 min_val, 850 max_val FROM dual
)
SELECT r.description, count(creditscore)
  FROM ranges r
       LEFT OUTER JOIN customer c 
         ON (c.creditscore BETWEEN r.min_val AND r.max_val)
 GROUP BY r.description
```

Normally, you'd want to set up a permanent table with your ranges in case someone wants to add or modify them in the future.  But you can hard-code the ranges in your query like I do here.

Comment: Your query seems to give an extra output for the records between 300 and 499. I have updated the question please look.

Comment: @AngryPanda - Sorry, I had a `count(*)` rather than a `count(creditscore)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unpivot` in this case. 
Your answer-

```
Select * From
(
Select Sum(Col1) "[300, 499]", Sum(Col2) "[500, 699]", Sum(Col3) "[700, 850]"
From (
    Select Case 
            When Creditscore Between 300
                    And 499
                Then 1 Else 0 End As Col1,
            Case When Creditscore Between 500
                    And 699
                Then 1  Else 0 End Col2,
            Case When Creditscore Between 700
                    And 850
                Then 1  Else 0 End Col3
    From Customer
    )
)
Unpivot
(
  "Count"
  For
  "Description" In ("[300, 499]", "[500, 699]", "[700, 850]")
);
```

Result -

```
Description  Count
[300, 499]    0
[500, 699]    4
[700, 850]    3
```